plugin rollup-plugin-sass: Error: Can't find stylesheet to import
I have an issue with the @carbon/theme and the rollup-plugin-saas plugin.
[!] (plugin rollup-plugin-sass) Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
6 │ @use '@carbon/themes';

It looks like the rollup-plugin-saas cannot find the node_modules directory.
Is there a specific setup to use with rollup/sass/typescript/react for the @carbon/** packages?
Project sample: (run: npx rollup -c) to recreate the error:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jwtddm?file=rollup.config.js
Summary of my configuration:
This file styles.scss doesn’t compile:
@use '@carbon/themes';
@use 'colors';
h1 {
  color: colors.$h1-color;
}

but this one is fine (colors.scss is in the same directory as styles.scss):
// @use '@carbon/themes';
@use 'colors';
h1 {
  color: colors.$h1-color;
}

package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.79.2",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.14.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/themes": "^11.43.0"
  }

rollup.config.ts
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'iife', // Suitable for <script> tags in browsers
    },
    plugins: [
        sass({ output: 'dist/styles.css' }), // Output CSS to a file
        terser() // Minify JavaScript
    ]
};


There is an includePaths option that can be used to specify where the node_modules are located:
sass(
   {
    output: 'dist/styles.css',
    options: {
        includePaths: ['node_modules']
    }
})

